# How to convert all HTML img close tags to be XML-compliant? (<img> to <img/>)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, regex, xml-parsing, sql-server-2014

**The Task:** We're scraping HTML for content via HttpWebRequest (some 6,000 calls).  This string is trimmed and stored in a SQL Server 2014 database for  processing as XML.

**The Problem**: In SQL Server, we'll get an XML parsing error: "`...end tag does not match start tag`" due to the image tags.

Now, I have a rather inelegant and ***potentially*** flawed solution in SQL Server.

**Sample String**

```
<div someattr="aaa">
    <div class="bbb">Some Text</div>
    <img src="image.jpg" width="150">      <-- Notice the lack of />
</div>
```

**Desired Results**

```
<div someattr="aaa">
    <div class="bbb">Some Text</div>
    <img src="image.jpg" width="150"/>      <-- Notice the />
</div>
```

I've tried countless Regex combinations in ASP.Net, and I seem to do more harm than good.  Any guidance or direction would be appreciated.

Respectfully,

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use an HTML parser und store the data in a better way than just a string. But if you're going for a quick and dirty solution with a regular expression, this might help you:

Look for this regex:

```
(<img[^>]*?[^\/]\s*)(>)
```

And replace it with:

```
$1/$2
```

- `[^>]*?` looks for any character except `>` but as few as possible
- `[^\/]\s*` makes sure, that the last character before `>` is either not a slash `/` or not a slash followed by white space
- The first and second part are grouped in `$1` and `$2`. It will only match, if there is not already a slash, and if it is an `img` tag.
- It won't work, if there is a `>` character as a string in between the `<img ...>` tag or if the tag is not closed at all `<img title=""`.

---

*Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/HIxIIR/1*

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for

Comment: Will award the bounty in 2 hours, when the system allows it

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert your html to xhtml first, there are some converters out there. regex and html didn't worked for me either...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately HTML does not have to be valid XML (except XHTML). So you have expect unclosed tags. HTML explicitely does allow some tags to be unclosed like `<br >` and is build to be robust even if there are really missing or even overlapping tags, which are actual errors even in HTML.

Depending on what HTML you expect you can try to correct some of these errors to XML. For example you know it will always be the same over all structure with different attribute values and content. If the HTML you get can be anything, I am afraid you are out of luck. Maybe you can store it as NVARCHAR(MAX) and if you have to query it on the database use `LIKE`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a quick and dirty solution that only uses T-SQL.

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TLF34624

```
CREATE FUNCTION processHtml(@html VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @remainingHtml VARCHAR(MAX),
            @processedHtml VARCHAR(MAX),
            @imgPos INT,
            @closingAngleBracketPos INT,
            @openingAngleBracketPos INT;
    SET @remainingHtml = @html;
    SET @imgPos = PATINDEX('%<img%[^</]>%', @remainingHtml);
    WHILE @imgPos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @processedHtml = CONCAT(@processedHtml, SUBSTRING(@remainingHtml, 1, @imgPos - 1));
        SET @remainingHtml = SUBSTRING(@remainingHtml, @imgPos, LEN(@remainingHtml));
        SET @closingAngleBracketPos = PATINDEX('%[^/]>%', @remainingHtml);
        SET @openingAngleBracketPos = CHARINDEX('<', @remainingHtml, 2);
        IF @closingAngleBracketPos < 0
            SET @imgPos = -1;
        ELSE IF @closingAngleBracketPos < @openingAngleBracketPos
        BEGIN
            SET @processedHtml = CONCAT(@processedHtml, SUBSTRING(@remainingHtml, 1, @closingAngleBracketPos), '/>');
            SET @remainingHtml = SUBSTRING(@remainingHtml, @closingAngleBracketPos + 2, LEN(@remainingHtml));
            SET @imgPos = PATINDEX('%<img%[^</]>%', @remainingHtml);
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @processedHtml = CONCAT(@processedHtml, SUBSTRING(@remainingHtml, 1, @openingAngleBracketPos - 1));
            SET @remainingHtml = SUBSTRING(@remainingHtml, @openingAngleBracketPos, LEN(@remainingHtml));
            SET @imgPos = PATINDEX('%<img%[^</]>%', @remainingHtml);
        END
    END

    SET @processedHtml = CONCAT(@processedHtml, @remainingHtml);
    RETURN @processedHtml;
END
```